# Loop through a list of strings and remove all items after a specific list item(i) where i can be a or b or c

Tags: python, python-3.x

Search through the list and remove everything else inclusive and after either Audi or Mazda or Suzuki. Please note **Only one** of the 3 can be in the list but **not** two or all of them. **Just one of them**

First Scenario: `if it's Audi,` 
Give a list (list items are random):

```
lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Audi","Mercedes","BMW","Subaru","Mitsubishi"]
```

Expected result:

```
new_lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet"]
```

Scenario 2 : `If it's Suzuki`.

Expected result

```
lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Mercedes","BMW","Subaru","Suzuki","Mitsubishi"]

new_lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Mercedes","BMW","Subaru"]
```

etc etc

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.takewhile` to crate a new list and 'break' out at the appropriate point

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Audi","Mercedes","BMW","Subaru","Mitsubishi"]
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x != "Audi", lst))
['Nissan', 'Chevrolet']
```

Comment: Looking at your interesting answer using `takewhile` (which is new to me, rookie here), is there a way to implement multiple criteria as per OP his needs? I guess that would make the answer more applicable.

Comment: @JvdV `takewhile` can take *any* function, e.g. `lambda x: x not in {"Audi", "Suzuki"}`

Comment: That sounds perfect in OP's scenario then =). The other answers (including my own) would error out when list would not contain *any* of the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Use list slicing with `list.index`

**Ex:**

```
lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Audi","Mercedes","BMW","Subaru","Mitsubishi"]
print(lst[:lst.index("Audi")])

lst = ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Mercedes","BMW","Subaru","Suzuki","Mitsubishi"]
print(lst[:lst.index("Suzuki")])
```

**Output:**

```
['Nissan', 'Chevrolet']
['Nissan', 'Chevrolet', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Subaru']
```

Comment: You haven't actually removed anything from `lst`, have you? `lst` has remained unchanged. A small point perhaps, but ...

Comment: you traverse the list twice, but you only need to traverse it once

Comment: @Booboo OP has `lst` and `new_lst`, so it seems he actually wants to create a new list here.

Comment: @Booboo. The above example is just to show a demo of list slicing with indexing. hence the `print` statement